# Keyboard not working in Lenovo Yoga 14

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, 16.04, windows-10

I recently formatted my Lenovo Think Pad Yoga 14 in order to change Windows 10 to the newly released Ubuntu 16.04.

After installing, everything works fine except for the keyboard. I can use a USB keyboard, however that is not an acceptable solution.

Surprisingly, when accessing the BIOS the keyboard works fine. However, when it starts booting Ubuntu, the Fn key led light is switched off and the keyboard doesn't work anymore.

Anyone has faced this problem? I tried installing Ubuntu 15 but the same problem occurred.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04? Maybe this issue could be related with some error during installation process.

Comment: No, however as I mentioned I tried again with 15.04 and (now) 14 but nothing changes. I even need the external keyboard at installation time.

Comment: Hence this problem is related with all version of Ubuntu that you tried? Have you already tried to update the kernel to version 4.5 or above? Perhaps it's only a missing drivers problem since your hardware is quite new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using [Johannes Wilm's thinkpad-yoga-14-s3-scripts on GitHub](https://github.com/johanneswilm/thinkpad-yoga-14-s3-scripts) that fix rotation and backlight. Apparently, the laptop was always in tablet mode, hence the keyboard was always disabled.

Include the following commands in `/etc/rc.local` so they are always executed at startup:

```
systemctl start yoga-rotate@username.service
systemctl start yoga-backlight@username.service
```

This trick solved the issue.